# Using MS SQL 2008 to replace an ASCII character

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

This has been touched on here but all of the examples I have tried failed to work

I have a nvarchar field that contains one or more characters that are < 32 and/or > 127. This is causing my query to return less that it should. I have tried the REPLACE([description],'[^\x20-\x7E]', 'XX') AS NewDescription and it did not work. I have read that you can't use regex in a sql statement.? Or I am not using the regex correctly.

Requirements:
MS SQL 2008
Can only use things that will run in a script. So no functions or stored procs.
I have no control over the data that is coming in.
Must have character fixed at the select level and the where level.

Comment: What does your query that returns 'less than it should' look like?

Comment: You may be able to achieve what you want with an appropriate collation to make SQL Server match strings like you want them to, without having to replace characters. What are you ultimately trying to achieve? What you're directly asking for is possible but any solution will be hard to maintain and inefficient.

Comment: This may be a better example.

Comment: @DonnieCrump: what's "this"?

Comment: Sorry. I hit enter to return and it posted.

This may be a better example.
my conditional is [description] = 'this -is a condition'.

Good statement
'this -is a condition'

Bad statement
'this -is a condition'

They look the same but in the bad one the hyphen is actually character 150.

I need to remove or change all ascii code characters less than 32 or greater than 127.

Comment: Have you tried  [description] = N'this -is a condition' ?   Or are you trying to compare 150 to -?

Comment: So far I am comparing - to 150. The reason I need a range changed is there could be more erroneous characters in the future.

So let's say today the char is 150 but tomorrow there is another in a different value. Say 155. What I had planned to do is change all chars <32 and >127 to a standard - (hyphen). That way all chars not in range would have a common character. This way if I got a bad character I could change my conditional to have a hyphen. It is not the best way but it will do for now.

Comment: @DonnieCrump: as there is no efficient way of doing that in SQL, you may want to relax your requirements. Also, your solution may be going way too far, since it also means that *anything* that is not a standard ASCII character will not be matched, even if users might want to match them. If the character was really supposed to be a hyphen, consider handing off the responsibility for that to who or whatever inserted the wrong data.

Comment: I think that is what I will have to do. I am going to look for 150 and change it to hyphen. And handle all other bad characters when they arise. I will take it back to business and have them address it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use REGEX in SQL.  Too bad you can't write a function, but the code you could use in a function can be used in a script, it will just be ugly.  Loop through the characters in your string and check the ASCII() value of each character to see if it's in the 32-127 range, and replace or omit as desired.

If you are doing this in the context of a result set, you'll need to use a cursor so you can populate a varchar variable and loop through the characters in the variable.   This is why it would be much prettier as a function.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write a function for such string manipulation. here is the sample code to replace all such characters

You can also do such things using CLR function as it would be faster that way.

```
    declare @string nvarchar(256) 

    DECLARE @r  NVARCHAR(256) = N''
    DECLARE @len INT = LEN(@string)
    DECLARE @i   INT = 1

    WHILE @i <= @len BEGIN
        DECLARE @char NCHAR(1) = SUBSTRING(@string, @i, 1)
        IF(UNICODE(@char) < 0x20) AND UNICODE(@char) > 0x7e
            SET @r += 'XX' 
        ELSE
            SET @r += @char
        SET @i += 1
    END
    SELECT @r
```